# What does it mean that ARSession.run(_: options) runs asynchronously after its called?

Tags: arkit

The last sentence of the Apple Documentation for ARSession.run(_:options) in the the discussion section states:

[ARSession.run(_:options)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/2875735-run?changes=latest_minor)https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/2875735-run?changes=latest_minor

> ”After you call this method, the session runs asynchronously.”

What do this mean?

Does it mean it runs on a different thread from the main forever?

Or

Does it mean that while it is transitioning from the previous session to new session it will be rerunning on a different thread?

Or

Does it mean something else?

I really want like to know/understand and would really appreciate any kind soul out there who would like to give some insight:-)

Thank you to the kind ARKit community,
We all learn by sharing what we know
Smartdog

Answer (score 1):

“(A)synchronous” doesn’t have to mean multithreaded.

I’m pretty sure all they mean by that is:

- the `run(_:options:)` call returns immediately
- the session is an ongoing process (at least partly in the main run loop, since it has per-frame callbacks, but possibly also involving other threads you don’t see)

This would be in contrast calls that are “synchronous” meaning that all effects of the call complete before it returns.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to shed a little more light on Apple documentation for `run(_:options:)`.  Your comments on ARKit have helped me out a great deal.  Thank you again. Smartdog